# Find a Lipschitz constant for $f(t,x)=x(\sin(t-x^2))$ in the region $0 \le t \le 2\pi$, $|x| \le M$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Just like the title, find a Lipschitz constant for $f(t,x)=x(\sin(t)-x^2)$ in the region $0 \le t \le 2\pi$, $|x| \le M$

I know that I have $|f(x)-f(y)| \le L |x-y| $ where I need to kind of 'break down' my equation and then find an L based on my interval, but I've never seen an equation written with the $t$ in it as above.  I've done a couple of these before, but none have depended on $t$ which is where I'm thrown off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing the differential of $f,$ you get 
$$\nabla f(t,x)=(x\cos(t),\sin(t)-3x^2).$$
As we have $||\nabla f(t,x)||^2=x^2\cos^2(t)+(\sin(t)-3x^2)^2,$ so for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$ and $|x|\leq M$ it gives
$$||\nabla f(t,x)||^2\leq x^2+1+9x^4+6x^2\leq 1+ 7M^2+9M^4.$$
Finally, using the mean value inequality, I get for $t,t'\in[0,2\pi]$ and $x,x'\in[-M,M]$ :
$$|f(t',x')-f(t,x)|\leq\sup\limits_{(t'',x'')\in[(t,x),(t',x')]}||\nabla f(t'',x'')||\cdot|(t',x')-(t,x)|\leq L\cdot||(t',x')-(t,x)||$$
with $L=1+ 7M^2+9M^4.$

Comment: Question for you, I believe I understand everything up until you have the $L\cdot||(t',x')-(t,x)||$.  I see in your edits that you originally had only a single $|$ along each side, which would make more sense to me.   So is it turning a vector into a scalar, or am I missing something completely?

Comment: I have replaced $|$ by $||$ just because the elements $(t,x)$ and $(t',x')$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ : so we don't work with the absolute value, but with a norm, which is exactly turning a vector into a scalar as you said.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome !